# Empty Info.plist paths in build settings with frameworks installed with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I have a problem with CocoaPods, every time I try to run the command `pod install` the pods are correctly installed but the Info.plist file path in the build settings of each linked framework is always empty and this causes errors when I try to install and run my app.

This my Podfile, I am using react-native:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

def add_flipper_pods!
  version = '~> 0.33.1'
  pod 'FlipperKit', version, :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin', version, :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin', version, :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin', version, :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitReactPlugin', version, :configuration => 'Debug'
end
# Post Install processing for Flipper
def flipper_post_install(installer)
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'YogaKit'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
      end
    end
  end
end


target 'myproject' do

  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga', :modular_headers => true

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '5.7'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '5.7'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '5.7'

  use_modular_headers!
  use_native_modules!

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  # add_flipper_pods!
  # post_install do |installer|
  #  flipper_post_install(installer)
  # end

end
```

I have already tried to clean the cocoapods cache, reinstall the pods, delete Xcode derived folder but nothing seems to fix this.

The Info.plist files are in the `Pods/Target Support Files/*myframework*/*myframework*-Info.plist`.

Is there a way to create a custom post-install rule to reassign them correctly?
It seems like the pod update corrupts them.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, I created this post-install script and I fixed the issue:

```
def info_post_install(installer)
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['INFOPLIST_FILE'] = 'Target Support Files/'+target.name+'/'+target.name+'-Info.plist'
        end
    end

end

post_install do |installer|
  info_post_install(installer)
end
```

I have posted it in case someone else will have this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same issue with Xcode 15.1.0, I had to revert Cocoapods to a previous version, then pod deintegrate then pod update. That did the trick for me